# No module found Pillow

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

So I am trying to install Pillow for a project, and I use cmd and pip3 install Pillow. After I installed it when i try to import Pillow in a file it says that the module doesn't exist. But when I go to cmd and run the command again I get this

`Requirement already satisfied: pillow in ....\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (7.0.0)`

PS: I am new to this.

Comment: If you are using IDE'sPyCharm

Comment: You should at least show your import statement so we can see which module name you are using.

Comment: you should run python3, then import PIL. Just check on cmd by typing 'python3'

Answer (score 0):

You use the name `pillow` to install it however you `import PIL` e.g

```
from PIL import Image
```

I suggest you work your way through [pillow tutorial](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html) if you're new to working with pillow.

Comment: I tried to import PIL but I still get no module named PIL

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed? e.g you installed the module with pip3 for Python 3.8 but you're running the script in Python 2 or Python 3.5 etc...?

Comment: Yes I do have python 2.7 and 3.8

Comment: How are you running your script? If you're running it from IDLE then check you've opened the correct version of IDLE (version number is at the top), if you are just double-clicking the file then check that the default Python to run is Python3 (right-click, open with, select python3 then "always open with....") if you are running in from CMD check you are doing "python3 my_script.py" and not "python my_script.py"

Comment: I'm running it with python3

Comment: To double-check you're running the same versions for both pip and you're script, open up CMD, and do `python3 -m pip install pillow` then `python3 path/to/your/script.py`. Installing with using `pip` via the `python -m` command ensures that the install and running your script are definitely using the same version of Python

Comment: I even tried to install pillow with PyCharm and Project Interpreter and it says `The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.`

Comment: I entered the commands and it says the same thing `Requirement already satisfied: pillow in ...\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (7.0.0)`

Comment: Are you still trying to run the script in PyCharm or does the script not run even when running it from CMD. If you are running it from PyCharm then that's vital information you should have put in your original question. [A quick search of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pycharm+pillow) shows lots of other people with the same problem, so maybe try searching first??

Comment: At first I used cmd and vs code to run the file, but then when i saw it doesn't recognize pillow as a module I also tried to run it with PyCharm